# Coefficients of the monomials appearing in a Schubert polynomial

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, ac.commutative-algebra, schubert-calculus, schubert-varieties

It is known that the coefficients of the monomials appearing in a [Schubert polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schubert_polynomial) are always positive. My question is: Is it always true that at least one such coefficient must be $1$? If that is not always true, then is it true that the gcd of the coefficients of the monomials appearing in a Schubert polynomial must always be $1$?

Comment: I suspect that for each permutation $w \in S_n$, each monomial appearing in the Schubert polynomial $\mathfrak{S}_w$ is lexicographically smaller-or-equal to the monomial $\mathbf{x}^{L\left(w\right)} := \prod\limits_{i=1}^n x_i^{\ell_i\left(w\right)}$, where $\ell_i\left(w\right)$ denotes the number of all $j > i$ satisfying $w\left(i\right) > w\left(j\right)$. Moreover, I suspect that the coefficient of this monomial $\mathbf{x}^{L\left(w\right)}$ is $1$.

Comment: @darij grinberg : can you please explicitly state what lexicographic order you are talking about here ?

Comment: The lexicographic order in which $x_1^{a_1} x_2^{a_2} x_3^{a_3} \cdots > x_1^{b_1} x_2^{b_2} x_3^{b_3} \cdots$ if and only if the smallest $i$ satisfying $a_i \neq b_i$ satisfies $a_i > b_i$. Sorry for not being precise before; there are indeed several lexicographic orders.

Comment: Probably it should not be too hard to see this from the "pipe dreams" definition of Schubert polynomials.

Comment: @darij grinberg : thanks for clarifying your lexicographic order ... but I don't quite see how the coefficient $1$ conjecture would follow from your conjecture ... could you elaborate here please ?

Comment: @Sam Hopkins: I thought so initially too ... but I don't quite see any pattern ... please do feel free to give your inputs

Comment: As I said, I suspect that the leading coefficient is $1$.

Comment: @darij grinberg : umm ... I thought you said the coefficient of $x^{L(w)}$ is $1$ ... does $x^{L(w)}$ always occur in the Schubert polynomial of $w$ ?

Comment: I think this is claimed at the beginning of the proof of Proposition 1.4 of the Billey-Jockush-Stanley paper (bottom of pg. 357): https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1023/A:1022419800503.pdf

Comment: @misao: I said that the coefficient of $\mathbf{x}^{L\left(w\right)}$ in $\mathfrak{S}_w$ is $1$ (in particular, this monomial must thus occur in $\mathfrak{S}_w$), and that all other monomials are smaller in lex order. But I also said that this is all speculation :) Maybe Sam's reference helps (I regret I don't speak its language).

Comment: Look at Corollary 3.9 of "RC-Graphs and Schubert Polynomials" by Bergeron and Billey: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.em/1048516036. It describes the (unique) leading term of a Schubert polynomial.

Comment: See also Lemma 4.11 here: http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1995-08-02/S0894-0347-1995-1290232-1/S0894-0347-1995-1290232-1.pdf

Comment: Darij's suspicion is correct: The leading coefficient is $x^{L(w)}$. This is transparent to see from the Kohnert formula for Schubert polynomials (e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.00088). (Some people don't believe some proofs of this formula, but I think everyone believes the formula!)

Answer (score -1):

It is known that the Schubert polynomials is an integral basis for the polynomials (if it was not a basis, then the problem of expanding a product of Schubert polynomials into Schubert polynomials would be kind of strange). That the basis is integral means that monomials expands into Schubert with integer coefficients.

As mentioned in the comments, there is an ordering such that the leading coefficient in this ordering is $1$ - this property implies that the basis is integral (is it perhaps equivalent to this property)?

Comment: The integral basis property is precisely Corollary 3.9 of the paper of Bergeron and Billey I referenced above.